# What will happen if i install a wlan driver package using wine

Tags: networking, drivers, wine

I am usin a HP laptop. The problem is the built in wifi device is not working. The laptop is dual boot with windows and the wifi is working perfectly on windows. Now i am using a usb wifi adapter for linux. My question is is there a way to install windows wifi drivers in linux. I saw some answers related this in askubuntu. But i cant unzip that driver file(.exe file). Can anyone help me. and another question is What will happen if i install a wlan driver package using wine. Thanks

The output of `lspci -vvnn` shown below

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Integrated Graphics [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 127
    Region 0: Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 2: Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Not Supported
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR-, OBFF Disabled
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee00018  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] #1b
    Capabilities: [200 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
        ATSCtl: Enable-, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
    Capabilities: [300 v1] #13
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: Memory at b1220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at b1232000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 124
    Region 0: Memory at b1210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00278  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin C routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at b1233000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot-,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: 00000000  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 128
    Region 0: Memory at b1234000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee002f8  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 125
    Region 0: Memory at b1230000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Region 1: Memory at b1237000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 5080 [size=8]
    Region 3: I/O ports at 5088 [size=4]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5060 [size=32]
    Region 5: Memory at b1235000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee00298  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0 BAR4 Offset=00000004
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d14] (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: b1100000-b11fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #5, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <16us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug- Surprise-
            Slot #4, PowerLimit 10.000W; Interlock- NoCompl+
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState-
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
        RootCap: CRSVisible-
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABC, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Not Supported ARIFwd+
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled ARIFwd-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee00218  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [103c:8328]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Capabilities: [200 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=40us PortTPowerOnTime=44us
    Capabilities: [220 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [8086:9d15] (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: b1000000-b10fffff
    Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort+ <SERR- <PERR-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
        PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
    Capabilities: [40] Express (v2) Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0
            ExtTag- RBE+
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable+ Non-Fatal+ Fatal+ Unsupported+
            RlxdOrd- ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 128 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #6, Speed 8GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <1us, L1 <16us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep+ BwNot+ ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive+ BWMgmt+ ABWMgmt-
        SltCap: AttnBtn- PwrCtrl- MRL- AttnInd- PwrInd- HotPlug- Surprise-
            Slot #5, PowerLimit 10.000W; Interlock- NoCompl+
        SltCtl: Enable: AttnBtn- PwrFlt- MRL- PresDet- CmdCplt- HPIrq- LinkChg-
            Control: AttnInd Unknown, PwrInd Unknown, Power- Interlock-
        SltSta: Status: AttnBtn- PowerFlt- MRL- CmdCplt- PresDet+ Interlock-
            Changed: MRL- PresDet- LinkState-
        RootCtl: ErrCorrectable- ErrNon-Fatal- ErrFatal- PMEIntEna- CRSVisible-
        RootCap: CRSVisible-
        RootSta: PME ReqID 0000, PMEStatus- PMEPending-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABC, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Not Supported ARIFwd+
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled ARIFwd-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Address: fee00258  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port [103c:8328]
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt+ RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap- CGenEn- ChkCap- ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Access Control Services
        ACSCap: SrcValid+ TransBlk+ ReqRedir+ CmpltRedir+ UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
    Capabilities: [200 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=40us PortTPowerOnTime=44us
    Capabilities: [220 v1] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP PMC [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Region 0: Memory at b122c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pmc_core

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 32, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 129
    Region 0: Memory at b1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at b1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee00318  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at b1236000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Region 4: I/O ports at 5040 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Hanksville Gbe Lan Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8328]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 126
    Region 0: I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b1104000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 4: Memory at b1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee002b8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 01
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 4096 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message/WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
        Vector table: BAR=4 offset=00000000
        PBA: BAR=4 offset=00000800
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [140 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [160 v1] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [178 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=150us PortTPowerOnTime=150us
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Region 2: Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1+ D2+ AuxCurrent=375mA PME(D0+,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [70] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 <64us
            ExtTag- AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
        DevCtl: Report errors: Correctable- Non-Fatal- Fatal- Unsupported-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag- PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- UncorrErr- FatalErr- UnsuppReq- AuxPwr+ TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <64us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp-
        LnkCtl: ASPM L1 Enabled; RCB 64 bytes Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s, Width x1, TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Not Supported, TimeoutDis+, LTR+, OBFF Via message/WAKE#
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis-, LTR+, OBFF Disabled
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 2.5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete-, EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2-, EqualizationPhase3-, LinkEqualizationRequest-
    Capabilities: [100 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- NonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, GenCap+ CGenEn- ChkCap+ ChkEn-
    Capabilities: [148 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=ff
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [168 v1] Device Serial Number 00-e0-4c-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 3145728ns
        Max no snoop latency: 3145728ns
    Capabilities: [180 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1- ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1- L1_PM_Substates-
```

and the out put of `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 18:60:24:ba:93:9b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: wlx7c8bca1ce553
       serial: 7c:8b:ca:1c:e5:53
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.0.48 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: Windows aint Linux and Linux aint Windows. "The problem is the built in wifi device is not working." Fix that problem by following the regular tests and include those into the question (like what is the chipset for instance). You can't use wine for this. For using windows drivers there is ndiswrapper (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper ) but HP has an excellent track record regarding Linux. "The problem is the built in wifi device is not working" has a solution from inside Linux. Please provide details: start with adding the results of `lspci -vvnn` into the question

Comment: ... and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the reply, added the details that you want.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not an answer to your question, it's ment to be a solution for your not working wifi-card.** 
*(I would write a comment, but the answer is way too long for it.)*

Regarding to https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek_RTL8723DE_Combo_Module you need the `RTL8723DE` driver for your wifi-card.

Regarding to https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/Karten/Realtek/ --> https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-findet-keine-drahtlosnetzwerke/2/#post-8917818 (german forum) the installationprocedure is the following:

*I am trying to translate the page, if any other can do better, please feel free to edit my post*

**Installationprocedure for Realtek rtl8723de [10ec:d723]**

**Until Kernel 4.10**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
git clone -b 4.10-down https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

If necessary uninstall

```
sudo dkms remove -m rtl8723de -v 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/
```

**Since Kernel 4.11 and higher**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
git clone -b 4.11-up https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

If necessary uninstall

```
sudo dkms remove -m rtl8723de -v 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 --all
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtl8723de-5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/
```

**Alternative: Driverupdate with rtlwifi_new**

First uninstall as described above, in case the driver is or was beeing used. 
Than install with

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo cp /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6/firmware/rtlwifi/* /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

and reboot

In case that you experience a bad / low signal strength try

```
 echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

If that did not help to increase the signal strenth exchange `ant_sel=2` with `ant_sel=1` or `ant_sel=0`

Secure boot in UEFI should be deactivated.

If necessary uninstall

```
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all
sudo rm -r /usr/src/rtlwifi-new-0.6
```

Driverinformation:

```
modinfo rtl8723de
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-104-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8723de.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
description:    Realtek 8723DE 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE 
author:         PageHe  
srcversion:     DB5F059D138EB4060ED55A0
alias:          pci:v000010ECd0000D723sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723-common,phydm_mod
vermagic:       4.4.0-104-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           dma64:bool
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0) (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1) (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0) (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1) (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 0) (bool)
parm:           aspm:Set to 1 to enable ASPM (default 1) (int)
parm:           debug_level:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           debug_mask:Set debug mask (default 0) (ullong)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0) (bool)
parm:           ant_sel:Set to 1 or 2 to force antenna number (default 0) (int)
```

Comment: bro thanks for the answer. i will check this answer and update the status soon.

Comment: Sounds about right :-)

Comment: Nop its not working. I have done the above instructions step by step . after restart there is no wifi option showing. My device name is  `product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller`

Comment: i am sorry that it does not work. Your wifi is `2:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]` your ethernet card is `01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a process to install wireless drivers from Windows in Linux and Ubuntu. It is called *ndiswrapper*. From the man page:

> ndiswrapper - Linux kernel module and user space tool to load and run
>   Windows XP drivers for wireless cards

So, if you have the Windows driver .exe for Windows XP, it is quite possible to install the driver in Wine, drag and drop the .inf and .sys files appropriate to your architecture, either 32- or 64-bit, to your Desktop, for example, and install the driver using ndiswrapper; something like:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo ndiswrapper -i myXP.inf
```

I doubt that you have or can even find the .exe for Windows XP. As well, I haven't seen ndiswrapper work successfully with any newer, not end-of-life kernel version in a couple of years.

Is it theoretically possible? Yes. Is it actually possible? Probably not.

Comment: Thanks bro, Yea i heard about this and i tried for this, but the problem is i cant extract the driver.exe file. is it possible to get only the specific .inf file from any site?

Comment: Doesn't it install the driver file if you do, from the terminal: `wine your_file.exe`? After it does, you'd need to look around in .wine/drive_c/windows/ to find the file. However, why bother; the answer is exactly what @AlexOnLinux suggests.